# By definition of $\mathbb E(X\mid \sigma(Y))$ calculate $\mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)$ when $X$and $Y$ are discrete random variables.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

By definition of $\mathbb E(X\mid \sigma(Y))$ i want to show
$$\mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)=\sum x \mathbb P(X=x\mid Y=y)$$
 when $X$and $Y$ are jointly discrete  random variables.( Absolutely continues  case is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612150/by-definition-of-mathbb-ex-mid-sigmay-calculate-mathbb-ex-mid-y-y-w) ).  I want to know is my steps right or no. I need some explanation in the steps from start to end(declared with sign ?)

let $Y$ is a discrete random variable that take values 
$\{ a_1 ,a_2,\cdots ,a_n\}$. So $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(\{a_1\},\cdots , \{ a_n\})$ (??)

By definition $\forall A\in \sigma(Y)$

$$ \mathbb E \left( \mathbb E \color{red}{(}X\mid \sigma(Y)\color{red}{)}1_A\right)
=\mathbb E(X1_A)$$ 
since $A\in \sigma(Y)$ so $1_A$ is a function of $Y$ so i think i can write
$$\mathbb E \left( \mathbb E \color{red}{(}X|\sigma(Y)\color{red}{)}1_B(Y)\right)=\mathbb E(X1_B(Y))$$

$$RHS=\mathbb E(X1_B(Y))=\sum_{y\in B} \sum_{x} x \mathbb P(X=x,Y=y) $$

$$LHS=\mathbb E \left( \mathbb E \color{red}{(}X\mid \sigma(Y)\color{red}{)}1_B(Y)\right)
=E \left( \mathbb E \color{red}{(}X\mid Y\color{red}{)}1_B(Y)\right)
$$

$$=\mathbb E \left( g(Y) 1_B(Y) \right)=\sum_{y\in B} g(y) P(Y=y)
=\sum_{y\in B} \mathbb E(X\mid Y=y) P(Y=y)
$$
By unifying $LHS$ and $RHS$  , $\forall B$

$$\sum_{y\in B}  \mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)  \mathbb P(Y=y)=\sum_{y\in B} \sum_{x} x \mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)$$

I think(??) for $y\in \{ a_1 ,a_2,\cdots ,a_n\}$ i can write (since equation is for all $B$ ??)

$$ \mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)  \mathbb P(Y=y)= \sum_{x} x \mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)$$

so for $y\in \{ a_1 ,a_2,\cdots ,a_n\}$

$$ \mathbb E(X\mid Y=y) = \sum_{x} x \frac{ \mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)}{ \mathbb P(Y=y)}= \sum_{x} x \mathbb P(X=x\mid Y=y)$$.

This proof was for finite support(like $Y$ is binomial), is this valid
for countable support ?(like Poisson?).

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide or any clarification.

Comment: I didn't get what $B$ was in your above writing.  Assume $X:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\{Y(\omega) : \omega \in S\} = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$. Strictly speaking, $\sigma(Y)$ is a collection of subsets of the sample space $S$ (not necessarily subsets of $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$), but it is indeed equal to the set of all events of the type $\{Y \in A\}$ for all possible subsets $A \subseteq \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$.

Comment: Nothing changes if you assume $\{Y(\omega) \in \mathbb{R} : \omega \in S\} = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...\}$ is a countably infinite set, as opposed to a finite set $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$.

Comment: Note that there are no "jointly discrete" random variables: if $X$ and $Y$ take at most countable number of values, then so does $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, this is essentially correct, but now you are overcomplicating things: the discrete case can be handled much easier.

Namely, for any $y$ such that $\mathbb P(Y=y)>0$, 
$$
\mathbb E[ \mathbb E[ X\mid Y]1_{Y=y}] = \mathbb E[ X 1_{Y=y}]\\ = \mathbb E\Bigl[\sum_x x1_{X=x}1_{Y=y}\Bigr] = \sum_x x\mathbb E[ 1_{X=x,Y=y}] = \sum_x x\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y).
$$
On the other hand, 
$$
\mathbb E[ \mathbb E[ X\mid Y]1_{Y=y}] = \mathbb E[ X\mid Y=y]\mathbb E[ 1_{Y=y}]  = \mathbb E[ X\mid Y=y]\mathbb P(Y=y).
$$
Dividing these equalities by $\mathbb P(Y=y)$, we arrive at the statement.